# Can we parameterize Thread schedule details like Start Thread count, Initial delay etc. in Ultimate thread Group using csv/txt files?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, parameterization, threadgroup

We are trying to parameterize Thread schedule details like Start Thread count, Initial delay etc.
Since we have 50+ thread groups and handling them has become an issue.

Would like to know if Jmeter has any unknown feature for this or a workaround to achieve this?
[Can we parameterize these values from a csv/txt file?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDaqT.png)\

Note: We have 50+ thread groups, hence using ${__CSVRead} and retrieve different values didn't work out.

Have tried out ${__CSVRead} but since we need different values for each thread, this isn't working out.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of "known" feature - using either *user.properties* file or a custom .properties file, i.e.

```
thread.group.1.start.threads=10
thread.group.1.initial.delay=5
thread.group.2.start.threads=50
thread.group.1.initial.delay=20
etc.
```

and you will be able to use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the Ultimate Thread Group to read the values from the .properties file:

[image]

If you put the values into *user.properties* file - you won't need to do anything else, the file will be picked up automatically, if you decide going for the custom .properties file - you will need to pass it via `-q` command-line argument:

```
 jmeter -q /path/to/your/thread/group.properties -n t .....
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)